# Does Jenkins serve agent.jar's GPG key?

Tags: jenkins

I want to create an automated script to deploy/configure Jenkins agent on a new machine.  As per the [documentation](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds#Distributedbuilds-Launchagentheadlesslyfromagentbacktomasteroncommandline):

> A copy of agent.jar can be downloaded from http://yourserver:port/jnlpJars/agent.jar

However, I would like to add a bit of extra security and verify the GPG key of the downloaded file.  Does Jenkins provide it?  (E.g. to be found at another URL).

Comment: For the case if the answer is "no": https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-57907